# The probability that the sum of two random x y values from [0,10] is less than 13

Tags: probability, area

> Two numbers $x$ and $y$ are randomly selected between $0$ to $10$. Find the probability that their sum is less than $13$.

I am scratching my head here trying to figure this out...

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you please clarify:  when you say numbers 'between 0 to 10' ... do you mean the integers FROM 0 to 10 i.e. {0,1,2, ..., 10}? Or do you mean the real continuous domain (0,10)?

Answer (score 3):

Implicit in "randomly selected" is "with uniform density".  This means that
the probability of $(x,y)$ lying in a (measurable) subset of the square $[0,10] \times [0,10]$ is the area of that set divided by the area of the square.

[image: Probability proportional to area]

Answer (score 3):

We assume that "randomly selected between $0$ and $10$" means that we are dealing here with two random variables $X$ and $Y$ that are **independent** and **uniformly distributed** in the interval $[0,10]$. That implies that the pair $(X,Y)$ has joint distribution that is uniform in the square with corners $(0,0)$, $(10,0)$, $(10,10)$, and $(0,10)$.

The probability that the pair $(X,Y)$ lands in a **subset** $A$ of the square is the area of $A$ divided by the area $100$ of the square.

In our case, the region $A$ is the part of the square that lies above the line $x+y=8$. 
To find its area, draw a picture. It is perhaps easier to find the area of the part of the square that lies below $x+y=8$. That's an isosceles right triangle with legs $8$ and therefore area $32$. Thus $A$ has area $68$.

Comment: Why do we consider the line x+y = 8 instead of x+y = 13 [Find the probability that their sum is less than 13.]?

Comment: @Tamil:  Quite a few  hours after Robert Israel and I answered the question, someone, presumably OP, changed the original question which said the sum is greater than $8$, to sum is less than $13$.  I was not notified. The basic structure of the answer does not change, but now we want to find the area below the line $x+y=13$. The region above $x+y=13$ is an isosceles right triangle with legs $7$, so area $24.5$.The probability is then $\frac{100-24.5}{100}$.