# Joint Distribution of Independent, Uniform variables $P(A<B<C)$ on a given interval

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I searched several links within this site and came upon many questions regarding the sum of two variables, but haven't been able to find a question regarding three.

Here is the question I came across in my book:

"Three points $A$,$B$ and $C$ are selected at random from the interval $(8,12)$.

Find the probability that $A<B<C$.

The question didn't specify, but after researching, and looking at the chapter heading, I am assuming that $A$,$B$, and $C$ are independent and uniformly distributed.
I am assuming that based on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1047717/the-probability-that-the-sum-of-two-random-x-y-values-from-0-10-is-less-than-1).

The visualization I originally came up with was like so:
$|(-8)-----A-----B-----C-----(12)|$

Then, I set up my integral as:

$\frac1{20^3}\int_{-8}^{12} \int_{A}^{12} \int_{B}^{12}1 \,dC\,dB\,dA$  =$\frac16$

However, I'm not sure if that's correct.

A lot of other, similar, problems start graphing on an X, Y plane, so I am skeptical of my answer.

Like, I'm not sure if I should write it as a conditional probability either, such as $P(A<B<C)=P(B<C|A<B)$ or something similar.

I guess I am having trouble visualizing this problem with confidence and other, similar problems, and I would appreciate any and all clarifications! Thank you!

Comment: Intuitively, if they are independent, the different orders of the three should be equiprobable. Since there are $3!=6$ cases for the order, the probability is 1/6.

Comment: @Martin  Wow, that makes so much sense.  I think I was so focused on trying to solve in one way, that I didn't take a step back to look at it intuitively.